# Getting a new parameter from fb_close in ruby on rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have one fb_share in my app.
I have also a text field where I can Type some text and pass that message as text for fb share.

this is how my fb_share works.

```
<li class="facebook">
                <a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?ni=Aa&amp;app_id=<%= FACEBOOK_APP_KEY %>&amp;display=popup&amp;caption=http://smartfortheheart.org/&amp;description=<%= $fb_share_text %>&amp;name=<%= $fb_share_name %>&amp;picture=<%= request.base_url %>/design/HeartStrong/images/sts_logo.png&amp;link=http://www.sistertosister.org/app&amp;redirect_uri=<%= FB_CALL_BACK_URL %>','_self');"></a>
</li>
```

on entering any text in the text field for custom fb share message I change it via jquery using `onchange` function.

Normaly this goes to a fb window and on sharing or closing that page it returns a url fb_close with which further process takes place..
n in this fb_close page params is just post_id..
is there any way i can get the fb_shared message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to call a function in oncall and in that function pass a get an ajax call to a controller and set some session.

To save the text u entered and den back in ajax success you write your current window.location.